# SBT Helm plugin

Tags: scala, plugin

#### Description

I've created simple SBT plugin which enables creating Helm Charts

The main reasons:

- in Helm it is impossible to 'fetch' external files: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3276 which is very cumbersome when dealing with applications that are packaged multiple times with different configurations.
- want to package my application from one tool: SBT (I'm using sbt-native-packager to create the Docker image)
- didn't find already existing SBT plugin that enables Helm Charts creation

The description and usage can be found in the [Github repository README.md](https://github.com/kiemlicz/shelm)

The main plugin source: https://github.com/kiemlicz/shelm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/shelm/HelmPlugin.scala

```scala
package com.shelm

import java.io.FileReader
import java.security.SecureRandom
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import com.shelm.ChartPackagingSettings.{ChartYaml, ValuesYaml}
import com.shelm.exception.HelmCommandException
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{yaml, Json}
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.duration.{FiniteDuration, SECONDS}
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

object HelmPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = noTrigger

  object autoImport {
    val Helm: Configuration = config("helm")
    // format: off
    lazy val chartSettings = settingKey[Seq[ChartPackagingSettings]]("All per-Chart settings")

    lazy val prepare = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Download Chart if not present locally, copy all includes into Chart directory, return Chart directory")
    lazy val lint = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Lint Helm Chart")
    lazy val packagesBin = taskKey[Seq[File]]("Create Helm Charts")
    // format: on

    lazy val baseHelmSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
      chartSettings := Seq.empty[ChartPackagingSettings],
      prepare := {
        val log = streams.value.log
        chartSettings.value.map {
          settings =>
            val tempChartDir = ChartDownloader.download(settings.chartLocation, target.value, log)
            val chartYaml = readChart(tempChartDir / ChartYaml)
            val updatedChartYaml = settings.chartUpdate(chartYaml)
            settings.includeFiles.foreach {
              case (src, d) =>
                val dst = tempChartDir / d
                if (src.isDirectory) IO.copyDirectory(src, dst, overwrite = true)
                else IO.copyFile(src, dst)
            }
            settings.yamlsToMerge.foreach {
              case (overrides, onto) =>
                val dst = tempChartDir / onto
                if (dst.exists())
                  IO.write(
                    dst,
                    resultOrThrow(for {
                      overrides <- yaml.parser.parse(new FileReader(overrides))
                      onto <- yaml.parser.parse(new FileReader(dst))
                    } yield yaml.printer.print(onto.deepMerge(overrides))),
                  )
                else IO.copyFile(overrides, dst)
            }
            val valuesFile = tempChartDir / ValuesYaml
            val valuesJson = if (valuesFile.exists()) yaml.parser.parse(new FileReader(valuesFile)).toOption else None
            val overrides = mergeOverrides(settings.valueOverrides(valuesJson))
            overrides.foreach { valuesOverride =>
              IO.write(
                valuesFile,
                if (valuesFile.exists())
                  resultOrThrow(
                    yaml.parser
                      .parse(new FileReader(valuesFile))
                      .map(onto => yaml.printer.print(onto.deepMerge(valuesOverride)))
                  )
                else yaml.printer.print(valuesOverride),
              )
            }
            IO.write(tempChartDir / ChartYaml, yaml.printer.print(updatedChartYaml.asJson))
            cleanFiles ++= Seq(tempChartDir)
            tempChartDir
        }
      },
      lint := {
        val log = streams.value.log
        prepare.value.zip(chartSettings.value).map {
          case (chartDir, settings) =>
            lintChart(chartDir, settings.fatalLint, log)
        }
      },
      packagesBin := {
        lint.value.zip(chartSettings.value).map {
          case (linted, settings) =>
            val chartYaml = readChart(linted / ChartYaml)
            buildChart(
              linted,
              chartYaml.name,
              chartYaml.version,
              settings.destination,
              settings.dependencyUpdate,
              streams.value.log,
            )
        }
      },
    )
  }

  val random = new SecureRandom
  import autoImport._

  private[this] def lintChart(chartDir: File, fatalLint: Boolean, log: Logger): File = {
    log.info("Linting Helm Package")
    val cmd = s"helm lint $chartDir"
    val logger = new BufferingProcessLogger
    try {
      startProcess(cmd, logger)
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) if fatalLint =>
        throw new HelmCommandException(s"$cmd has failed: ${e.getMessage}, full output:\n${logger.buf.toString}", e)
      case NonFatal(e) =>
        log.error(s"$cmd has failed: ${e.getMessage}, full output:\n${logger.buf.toString}continuing")
    }
    chartDir
  }

  private[this] def buildChart(
    chartDir: File,
    chartName: String,
    chartVersion: String,
    targetDir: File,
    dependencyUpdate: Boolean,
    log: Logger,
  ): File = {
    val opts = s"${if (dependencyUpdate) " -u" else ""}"
    val dest = s" -d $targetDir"
    val cmd = s"helm package$opts$dest $chartDir"
    val output = targetDir / s"$chartName-$chartVersion.tgz"
    log.info(s"Creating Helm Package: $cmd")
    retrying(cmd, log)
    output
  }

  /**
    * Retry given command
    * That method exists only due to: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2258
    * @param cmd
    * @param sbtLogger
    * @param n number of tries
    * @return
    */
  private[shelm] def retrying(cmd: String, sbtLogger: Logger, n: Int = 3): Try[Unit] = {
    val logger = new BufferingProcessLogger()
    val sleepTime = FiniteDuration(1, SECONDS)
    val backOff = 2
    @tailrec
    def go(n: Int, result: Try[Unit], sleep: FiniteDuration): Try[Unit] =
      result match {
        case s @ Success(_) =>
          sbtLogger.info(s"Helm command success, output:\n${logger.buf.toString}")
          s
        case Failure(e) if n > 0 =>
          sbtLogger.warn(s"Couldn't perform: $cmd, failed with: ${e.getMessage}, retrying in: $sleep")
          Thread.sleep(sleep.toMillis)
          val nextSleep = (sleep * backOff) + FiniteDuration(random.nextInt() % 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          go(n - 1, Try(startProcess(cmd, logger)), nextSleep)
        case Failure(exception) =>
          val msg = s"Couldn't perform: $cmd, retries limit reached.\nProcess stderr and stdout:\n${logger.buf.toString}"
          sbtLogger.err(msg)
          throw new HelmCommandException(msg, exception)
      }
    go(n, Try(startProcess(cmd, logger)), sleepTime)
  }

  private[shelm] def startProcess(cmd: String, log: BufferingProcessLogger): Unit =
    sys.process.Process(command = cmd) ! log match {
      case 0 => ()
      case exitCode => sys.error(s"The command: $cmd, failed with: $exitCode")
    }

  private[this] def readChart(file: File) = resultOrThrow(
    yaml.parser.parse(new FileReader(file)).flatMap(_.as[Chart])
  )

  private[this] def mergeOverrides(overrides: Seq[Json]): Option[Json] = {
    val merged = overrides.foldLeft(Json.Null)(_.deepMerge(_))
    if (overrides.isEmpty) None else Some(merged)
  }

  override lazy val projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    inConfig(Helm)(baseHelmSettings)

  override def projectConfigurations: Seq[Configuration] = Seq(Helm)
}
```

SBT plugins tests: https://github.com/kiemlicz/shelm/tree/master/src/sbt-test/shelm

#### Questions

First and foremost: I would gladly receive any input and thoughts about this project

Open question: what do you think about plugin rationale?

Technical questions

1. Do you think that `task`s and `settings` are properly split?
2. When running plugin in parallel for multiple projects (the SBT parallelizes tasks by default) sometimes I encountered: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2258#issuecomment-306498450. The linked ticket somehow suggests it is an issue with Helm. Yet I've [created a workaround](https://github.com/kiemlicz/shelm/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/shelm/HelmPlugin.scala#L147) which simply retries the `helm` commands. I'm unsure if it is indeed issue with Helm or my code wrongly spawning the `helm` process
3. I've created dedicated SBT `Configuration` for my tasks, is it created and used properly?

```scala
object autoImport {
    val Helm: Configuration = config("helm")
...
}
```

4. Should I implement dedicated `clean` task or appending any artifacts to `cleanFiles` is sufficient?

```scala
cleanFiles ++= Seq(tempChartDir)
```

Thank you

EDIT:
I've provided the missing main plugin source as a snippet

Comment: For anyone in the close vote queue, the code is now included, that is not a reason to down vote or vote to close.

Comment: What is a helm chart supposed to convey?

Comment: K8s deployment yamls mainly. Helm provides nice versioning system, 'standarized' deplyoment procedures, templating engine. I consider Helm Chart as a complementary artifact to Docker images

Comment: Why in the code presented don't I find what it is good for?

Comment: Isn't the: https://github.com/kiemlicz/shelm#example what you are after? Or Should I elaborate more here in this post?

Comment: You can address whoever you want in a comment using @whoever: only the post/question owner gets notified by default. I, for one, review code presented *here*. And I commented I didn't find a raison d'être in the code presented above: I don't believe in separate documentation.